# Why was the tag removed from my question?

Tags: support, tags

I had added a tag ([soundmanager](/questions/tagged/soundmanager)) to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625500/strange-issue-setting-volume-on-my-music-player-soundmanager).

But the tag was deleted for some reason.

My mistake was that the tag I should have used was [soundmanager2](/questions/tagged/soundmanager2).

But that wouldn't be a reason to delete it, but rather change it.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You would have to ask the guy who removed it to get an answer.

Comment: I can't speak for Charles who removed it, but maybe it was merely removed because your post was the only one using it? Once you create such tag, low rep users can use it in their future posts too: pollution!

Comment: @Oded I know I should ask Charles, but I don't have his phonenumber ;)

Comment: You could `@` comment to him. I believe that will also notify him as someone who edited the post (though I could be wrong).

Comment: like how kenya and netherlands are different, in a similar fashion soundtrack and soundtrack2 are different

Comment: The @-syntax does indeed work when addressing post editors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason is as [Arjan said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117101/why-was-the-tag-removed-from-my-question#comment-306642), your question is the only question that has the [soundmanager](/questions/tagged/soundmanager) tag on it.

Given that your question was specifically about soundmanager *2*, and that there are at least 30 other questions with the [soundmanager2](/questions/tagged/soundmanager2) tag, the edit should have been to remove the [soundmanager](/questions/tagged/soundmanager) tag *and add* the [soundmanager2](/questions/tagged/soundmanager2) tag.

Note that tags for version-specific questions are not always appropriate; if the question applies across versions, then it's better to tag with the version-agnostic version of the tag.  If the question applies to a specific-version, then it's better to tag with the specific version tag *and possibly* the version-neutral tag.

This is a judgement call, since there's no [soundmanager](/questions/tagged/soundmanager) tag, you should really ask *"do I need to create one?"*.  Asking this question is usually a good indicator that you *don't* have to create a new tag (but not always).

Comment: Everything here is factually correct and reflects the reason I edited the tag out.  I happened to neglect my new-tag-deletionist duties in this case by not looking for alternate tags/spellings during the edit.

Comment: @Charles ok great. Thanks for getting back to me!